# Upgrading a DELL Precision T3400 graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, compatibility, pci-express

I'm looking to upgrade my older T3400's graphics card (Quadro FX 570).

I've been looking at a GeForce GTX 960 card, but I don't know if it would even be compatible. It says it requires a Pci-e 3.0 slot, does the computer have one that's compatible?

Comment: The `Quadro FX 570` is a PCI-E x16 card.  Provided you have a PCI-Ev3 slot then the `GTX 960` will function to it's full potential.

Comment: Even if it is, is it worth spending _any_ money on a core 2 duo system - It probably pays you - in Electricity consumption alone - to upgrade the motherboard/cpu.  The system is running an Intel Core 2 or Core 2 Duo CPU, which is old.   You also need to check if your PSU is the 575 watt model - the GTX960 requires 120 watts of power compared to 38 watts for the FX570.

Comment: @davidgo not to mention it only supports up to 8 GB of blazing fast PC2-5300 (DDR2 667 MHz) RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It says it requires a Pci-e 3.0 slot,

I doubt that, or they are stating it wrong. It performs best with PCI-e v3. But stating that it requires PCI-e v3 is about the same as saying a Porche needs a highway or it will not work.

PCI-e is backwares compatible. Which means it should run in any PCI-e slot. PCI-e v1, PCI-v2, PCI-v3 or future PCI-e v4.